# Use SURF to match images in OpenCV\EmguCV

Tags: c#, image-processing, opencv, emgucv, surf

I'm working on the source code from [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SURF_feature_detector_in_CSharp).

It seems that `indices` variable stores the match information, but I don't know how the information is stored.

For example, can you tell me how many matched pair of points are found? Which point matches which point?

Comment: Please post the code here.

Comment: My code is excatly the same with [the linked article](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SURF_feature_detector_in_CSharp). If I post it here, I think my post will be too long. Or is it a manner in stackoverflow that should post code in the question rather than link to other places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on this line.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> result = Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(modelImage, modelKeyPoints, observedImage, observedKeyPoints,
        indices, new Bgr(255, 255, 255), new Bgr(255, 255, 255), mask, Features2DToolbox.KeypointDrawType.DEFAULT);
```

The most important variable is **mask**. This variable has all need information. It is array. If value on this array is equal 1 that means that we have a common pair. You have to count how many times appears 1 in this array.

```
    public int CountHowManyPairsExist( Matrix<byte> mask)
    {
        var matched = mask.ManagedArray;
        var list = matched.OfType<byte>().ToList();
        var count = list.Count(a => a.Equals(1));
        return count;
    }
```