# EmguCV - Get number of matches for determining image similarity

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, surf

I am currently using SURF  algorithm (on EmguCV 3.1) to test whether two images might correspond to the same location [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKzgF.jpg) and a very dark version of it, which brings me the following 2 questions:

1-Do you think counting the number of good matches between the two pictures is a good idea for determining the image similarity? If not , any other suggestions ?

2-Assuming counting the number of matches is a good approach. How to get the count of matches ? Some articles talk about [counting the number of NonZeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657853/emgucv-surf-determine-matched-pairs-of-points?noredirect=1&lq=1) . However, results do no seem to match like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjkjw.jpg) , which shows only 2 matches , yet it returns  a value of 30 (variable noZeroCount). The code I'm using is this :

```
public static void FindMatch(Mat modelImage, Mat observedImage, out long matchTime, out VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints, out VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints, VectorOfVectorOfDMatch matches, out Mat mask, out Mat homography)
    {
        int k = 2;
        double uniquenessThreshold = 0.8;
        double hessianThresh = 300;

        Stopwatch watch;
        homography = null;

        modelKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
        observedKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
        using (UMat uModelImage = modelImage.ToUMat(AccessType.Read))
        using (UMat uObservedImage = observedImage.ToUMat(AccessType.Read))
        {
            SURF surfCPU = new SURF(hessianThresh, 4 , 2, true, true);

            //extract features from the object image
            UMat modelDescriptors = new UMat();
            surfCPU.DetectAndCompute(uModelImage, null, modelKeyPoints, modelDescriptors, false);

            watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            // extract features from the observed image
            UMat observedDescriptors = new UMat();
            surfCPU.DetectAndCompute(uObservedImage, null, observedKeyPoints, observedDescriptors, false);
            BFMatcher matcher = new BFMatcher(DistanceType.L2);
            matcher.Add(modelDescriptors);

            matcher.KnnMatch(observedDescriptors, matches, k, null);
            mask = new Mat(matches.Size, 1, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
            mask.SetTo(new MCvScalar(255));
            Features2DToolbox.VoteForUniqueness(matches, uniquenessThreshold, mask);

            int nonZeroCount = CvInvoke.CountNonZero(mask);
            if (nonZeroCount >= 4)
            {
                nonZeroCount = Features2DToolbox.VoteForSizeAndOrientation(modelKeyPoints, observedKeyPoints,
                   matches, mask, 1.5, 20);
                if (nonZeroCount >= 4)
                    homography = Features2DToolbox.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures(modelKeyPoints,
                       observedKeyPoints, matches, mask, 2);
            }

            watch.Stop();
            matchTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }
```

Much appreciated for any of your efforts.

Comment: Image1 seems to be little amenable to precise identification, as it is essentially a foliage texture with little salient features. Can we see the dark image ?

Comment: The case of "this picture" seems hopeless, there is nothing to see. Anyway, histogram equalization might improve on things.

Comment: @Yves , this is the darker version version of the image : http://imgur.com/jGDdl2G, same scene but less brightness . These are the real results,  http://imgur.com/24wwjHf when comparing the two images.

Comment: If the images are known to be taken from the same viewpoint, what's the point comparing for similarity ? If they are take from different viewpoints, expect to get quite different results. The comparison image is completely unreadable.

Comment: The images come from  a live web cam, with images being taken at a regular interval, the point of comparing the images is to check whether something is blocking (such as birds, spiders, etc.) or not ,the camera's view

Answer (score -2):

Using the nonZeroCount, the bigger this value, more similar between two images.

Comment: PLease add more detailed information about the topic you want to get help to like: technology, framework / language, error message, example code.