# How to find the amount of matches from feature extraction?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, feature-extraction, sift

I want to be able to get the number of matches of features from two images. Unfortunately I can't seem to find how to do it. I use the most recent EMGU package that can be downloaded from NuGet I have used the code from: [Feature Matching sample](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37863.c-image-recognition-with-emgu-libraries.aspx#FeatureMatching_sample), but the issue is that the method they use to count the values gives an error. It gives an error at this code block:

```
// Calculate score based on matches size
// ---------------------------------------------->
score = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Size; i++)
{
    if (mask.GetData(i)[0] == 0) continue;
    foreach (var e in matches[i].ToArray())
        ++score;
}
```

Specifically at `mask.GetDAta(i)[0]` and it then states that `int` cannot be converted to `bool`, but I honestly don't know what to fill in as parameter then.

A different solution I have seen is use the nonzero count but that seems incorrect. Furthermore, what is mentioned here [EmguCV SURF - Determine matched pairs of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657853/emgucv-surf-determine-matched-pairs-of-points?noredirect=1&lq=1) does not work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a mistake in their example, try this instead:

```
if ((byte)mask.GetData().GetValue(i, 0) == 0) continue;
```